# How can I find the intersection of two line segments that do not currently meet in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I have two line segments in an Adobe Illustrator file, line A and line B.

[image: two lines that don't meet]

I would like to find point C, the point where if line A were to continue down along its path and line B were to continue to the left, they would meet.

What is the best way to do that in Illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use **Smart Guides**, dragging your anchor to-and-fro for a moment to get the "line extension" Smart guide to show up, or you can draw your *own **guides***, snapping to the existing geometry; either approach works, and where some designers prefer one method, some designers prefer the other.

See screenshot below for **smart guides** line extension snapping:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> with segments selected converts those selected segments into custom guides - see screenshot below for custom guides.

[image]

Comment: In your Custom Guide example screenshot, it seems like just the two individual line segments of the square shapes have been turned into guides, but when I have a line segment selected and hit Ctrl-5, the entire shape that the line segment is a part of turns into a custom guide. In your example, were your line segments connected to the squares, or were the squares made of four individual, unconnected line segments?

Comment: Neither: I wanted to emulate your condition in which you wanted to extend one vertice to an arbitrary intersection point, so I had two square-tool squares, carefully unaligned. I then drew a line (using snapping with smart guides) along one of those baselines which was supposed to intersect and declared it a Custom Guide (Cntrl-5) and then repeated this action on the other square.
I did this so that it was a workflow mostly closely aligned with your question - something you can do once you have your initial figure(s) set up and realise you need to move a vert.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you for the clarification, and the original answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Transform Effect: select both paths and open menu Effect->Distort and Transform->Distort, set scale Horizontal and Vertical to some large value( in my example 400% will be enough):[image]

To return paths to normal state open Appearance Panel and delete Transform effect.

Comment: When you say select both paths, do you mean select the two endpoints of each path?

Also I don't have a "Distort" menu under the Effect menu, I have a "Distort and Transform" immediately under the Effect menu, so we might have a different version of Illustrator (I'm using the latest CC version). But, under that "Distort and Transform" menu I do have a "Transform" effect that matches the Transform Effect window in your screenshot. When I scale by a large amount, like 400%, it just scales my entire shape up to 400%. So I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I don't entirely follow :)

Comment: Yes, the right menu item: Effect->Distort and Transform->Distort.

'Select 2 paths' means select 2 separate paths (you can see it in a layer panel as a 2 separate items).
Your qustion was about 2 separate paths (not a shape that consist of a single path), since if you have a shape this method just scale this single path.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have said "two line segments". (If you look at the image in my original question, you can see it is indeed one 'path', I should have been more clear).

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. Thanks for your answer!